# How to add image in header of Excel using apache poi

Tags: header, apache-poi

currently I'm working with apache poi 3.9. In this case, I will create a header with an image. Here's the code

```
 byte[] logo;
 int logoId;
 Picture pict;
    try {
      logo = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/Users/xiia7/OneDrive/Documents/assets/images/logo.png"));
      logoId = workbook.addPicture(logo, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
      CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
      Drawing drawing = sheet0.createDrawingPatriarch();
      ClientAnchor  anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
      pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, logoId);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Header header = sheet0.getHeader();
    header.setCenter(HSSFHeader.font("Times New Roman", "Bold")+HSSFHeader.fontSize((short) 8)+ "&[Picture]");
```

And the result just like this, image was not occure
[image]

Is it possible if I add an image in header with 3.9 version's of poi ?

Comment: Apache POI does not provide methods for handling graphics (`&G`) in header/footer, neither for `XSSF` nor for `HSSF`. Using `XSSF` one could use the low level `CT*` classes. But for `HSSF` it becomes very challenging as there one would must implement special binary record objects first. And version 3.9 is far too old to bother with.

Comment: hello @AxelRichter I just updated my po version into 4.1.0. can you tutor to me how to add header with image using HSSF ?

Comment: Why not using current version 5?

Comment: ok, i will update the version into the 5.1.0. so, how to add header image in hssf?

Comment: That's good decision. But ,as said, for `HSSF` it becomes very challenging as there one would must implement special binary record objects first. Will try this weekend.

Comment: Sorry but cannot provide a solution for the Excel Binary File Format (.xls) (HSSF). There are too many binary records not implemented by Apache POI - [MS.XLS] records as well as [MS-ODRAW] records. So I would suggest using a template .xls file which has picture in header already.

Comment: ok @AxelRichter no problem, thank you for your help :)